# Use EMailMessage to to send email with embedded image and multipart text & html read from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, html-email

I want to send a multi-part email (text and html) using the Python 3 EMailMessage class, which also has an embedded image. I have been able to get it working when using the MIME classes, but not with the EMailMessage class. The HTML mail shows up but there is no embedded image, with it being added as an attachment instead. Example code is shown below (there are also lines commented out from my various attempts):

```
# Send an HTML email with an embedded image and a plain text message for
# email clients that don't want to display the HTML.
#Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib, ssl, mimetypes, imghdr

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from email.utils import make_msgid

STR_FROM_DISPLAY_NAME = "From Display Name"
TEXTFILE = "example.txt"
HTMLFILE = "example.html"
IMGFILE = "logo.png"
STR_FROM = "from@example.com"
STR_TO = "to@example.com"
STR_SUBJECT = f"The contents of {TEXTFILE}"

msg = EmailMessage()
msg["Subject"] = STR_SUBJECT
# STR_FROM == the sender's email address
# STR_TO == the recipient's email address
msg["From"] = STR_FROM
msg["To"] = STR_TO
msg.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

# Open the plain text file whose name is in TEXTFILE for reading.
with open(TEXTFILE) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# Add the html version.  This converts the message into a multipart/alternative
# container, with the original text message as the first part and the new html
# message as the second part.
image_cid = make_msgid()[1:-1]  # strip <>    
with open(HTMLFILE) as fp:
    msg.add_alternative(fp.read(), subtype="html") 
#.format(cid=cid), subtype="html")

#maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(IMGFILE)[0].split('/', 1)
# Now add the related image to the html part.
#attachments={"image1": IMGFILE}

#for png_cid in attachments:
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

with open(IMGFILE, "rb") as fp:
    image_type = imghdr.what(fp.name)
    print("image_type = ", image_type)

    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())

    # Define the image's ID as referenced above
    msgImage.add_header("Content-ID", "<image_cid>")
    msgImage.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', IMGFILE)
    msgImage.add_header("Content-Disposition", f"inline; filename={IMGFILE}")

#   msg.attach(msgImage)
   # Make the EmailMessage's payload `mixed`
    #msg.get_payload()[1].make_mixed()   # getting the second part because it is the HTML alternative
    #msg.get_payload()[1].attach(msgImage)

    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(msgImage, "image", image_type, fp.name, cid=image_cid) #.format(cid=cid))

#   logo = MIMEImage(img.read())
#   logo.add_header("Content-ID", f"cid")
#   logo.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', IMGFILE)
#   logo['Content-Disposition'] = f"inline; filename=" IMGFILE
#   msg.attach(logo)

    # Make the EmailMessage's payload `mixed`
#   msg.get_payload()[1].make_mixed()   # getting the second part because it is the HTML alternative
#    msg.get_payload()[1].attach(logo)

port = 465  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.mail.server.com"
password = "Password"

# Create secure connection with server and send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(STR_FROM, password)
    server.send_message(msg)
```

Below is the line from the HTML file where I specify the image:

```
<img class="image_fix" src="cid:{image_cid}" alt="Logo" title="Logo" width="637" height="213" />
```

There are lots of examples where the HTML is specified in the python code, but I haven't been able to find any where the HTML is loaded from a file where an image is embedded.

I also want to attach a word .docx file to the email, and I have sort of managed this with MIME classes, but the attachment did not show the size when viewed in the e-mail client. I used the line:

```
MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream").
```

with it encoded as base64. I think that there is a "word"/"docx" MIME type, but again not sure how to do it.

Any ideas ?